# How to persist additional data added on fly in Passport sessions

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express, passport.js

I have a simple authentication system built on Passport.js on top of Node.js. I have a use case where I need to persist Organisation ID in the session which is to be updated on hitting of a particular route.
I did this using the middleware:

```
app.use('/switchOrganization',function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.user) req.session.passport.user.activeOrg = 'my org';
    next();
});
```

But this doesn't persist the data in other routes:

```
app.route('/someRoute').post(function(req,res){
    console.log(req.session.passport.user);
});
```

It doesn't contains the 'activeOrg' value. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: see my edit. It was a mistake!

Answer (score 0):

The user object is deserialized into `req.user` in the `deserializeUser` function. **This happens on each request.** So if you make change to `req.user` in one of the route handlers, and expect it to be persisted for the route handlers that follow it, it'll only be the case for that particular request. If `/someRoute` is requested anew, it will not have the the changes you made in another route which wasn't invoked in the new request.

You should instead persist the changes to database so that when the `deserializeUser` function is called for the next request, it'll have your data from the beginning.

Comment: this is only the temporary data that i want to persist in session. There has to be some way to save data in session that remains till the session lasts. No?

Comment: In that case just store it in `req.session` https://github.com/expressjs/session#reqsession

Answer (score 0):

I am using redis `sessionStore`. And if I write to `req.session`, then data persists on redis store:

```
req.session.access_token = result.access_token;
req.session.refresh_token = result.refresh_token;
req.session.instance_url = result.instance_url;
```

[Redis Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YpKn.png)